# How to remove solidified paste from toothbrush

Tags: cleaning, personal-care

I have been using my current toothbrush for only about a month and it has already started developing deposits of solidified toothpaste on it(a significant amount). (It looks sort of like chewing gum stuck on it).

It is extremely difficult to remove manually due to the small spacings between the bristles. Only a very small amount can come out if you try to do manually (most of it stuck to the bottom of the tooth brush I believe). It also doesn't come out with running water.

Is there a way I can remove it? I think my toothbrush isn't cleaning as effectively due to this (not sure though).

Comment: You may be using **too much toothpaste**. Brushing action cleans away dental plaque—not toothpaste. According to most dentists you do not even need toothpaste for effective dental hygiene. Besides, dental floss does a better job between your teeth—not a brush—certainly not toothpaste in any flavour.

Comment: Possible. I make a thin layer of toothpaste for the entire length of the toothbrush.

Comment: Put the toothpaste in your mouth first. Much more effective distribution.

Comment: The quantity of toothpast shown in advertising is commercially misleading. With such a quantity you should be able to brush your teeth 3 to 5 times...

Comment: You only need a "pea" sized amount of toothpaste.

Comment: Not sure why this is considered a life hack. Most people rinse their toothbrushes. PRevention is better than cure.

Comment: Fill a glass with water, put the toothbrush in it, and allow it to soak overnight. Tomorrow you'll be able to get rid of the hardened toothpaste. Rinse the toothbrush out after every use to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Throw it away and start with a new one.

To prevent the build-up of toothpaste and other stuff on the brush, rinse it thoroughly after use and stand it so it can drain freely, like this.

[image]

Comment: +1. The stress is: really clean it after you use it. I never had any such problem in my life, using this "technique".

Comment: I infact follow this procedure. Maybe I didn't do it throughly enough

Comment: Stand it like that and then look in the cup you stand it in, a couple of months later - ugh! :)

Comment: @user600016: to be sure you do a good cleaning, run your (clean) finger through the hairs of the brush - that is what I do. Do not assume that the flowing water would do an acceptable job.

Comment: @user600016 You're doing _something_ wrong. I have never had anything like the problem you describe and I don't rinse my toothbrush thoroughly at all. I just hold it under the running tap for a couple of seconds. I suspect you're using much too much toothpaste, and possibly on a dry brush.

Comment: @CaiusJard Cup goes in the dishwasher every couple of weeks.

Comment: @CaiusJard what is your other sanitary ware like?

Comment: Oh, it wasn't a criticism.. I agree with your proposal and i clean the brush/stand it just as you do - i'm always amazed by the amount of eurgh in the bottom of the cup in such a short time

Comment: @user3067860 indeed. Got a one click detachable toilet seat too; that gets a very hot dishwash on a regular basis too!

Comment: "Invest in an ultrasonic toothbrush, stick it under the tap and turn it on" - they keep themselves, and your teeth, pretty clean

Answer (score 7):

Similar to SurpiseDog's answer, I find that very hot (tea brewing temperature) works very well. Simply fill a mug with the water and place the toothbrush in head down. I let it sit for a minute and then brush my teeth with no additional paste. If there is still paste, back into the hot water. Do this three or four times and the tooth brush will look brand new.

Also, you should only put about a pea sized amount of toothpaste on a toothbrush; more than that contributes greatly to the issue you are experiencing.

Please note, if the toothbrush is heavily worn, you should just replace it anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Hold the toothbrush under boiling water and that gunk should come right off.

This is also a great way to disinfect a toothbrush as the hot water will kill any bacteria.

Comment: Note that boiling water will not "insta-kill" bacteria. The EPA recommends 1 minute of boiling to disinfect water, and 3 minutes at high altitude. https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/1117/how-long-does-water-need-to-be-boiled-for-to-kill-all-bacteria-viruses

Comment: In the time it takes the water to heat up to boiling temperature, all the bacteria will be killed: http://www.princeton.edu/~oa/manual/water.shtml

Answer (score 2):

Put it in the dishwasher? That might work if its not on a too hot setting

Comment: Dishwashers max out at 75 degrees C, so this should be okay. - If the toothbrush can survive boiling water at 100C, it should survive the dishwasher okay. As this answer is the simplest, easiest and most effective, I think the OP should accept it.